# Can I pass a textInput to a Regex search

Tags: r, regex, shiny

I have a shiny app which searches text for a specific user defined character string.
I need to be able to have the user input the text they want to look for then insert it into the following code where I have typed INPUTTEXT

```
output$Table <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()%>%mutate(searchmatch<-str_extract(DocumentText,"([^\\s]+\\s){50}INPUTTEXT(\\s[^\\s]+){50}"))%>%select(-DocumentText)
    )
```

The user will type into a textInput box when the app runs.
I have named the textInput "SearchPhrase"

Any suggestions of how I can pass the searchphrase into the Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
str_extract(DocumentText, sprintf("([^\\s]+\\s){50}%s(\\s[^\\s]+){50}", input$SearchPhrase))
```

or

```
str_extract(DocumentText, paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){50}", input$SearchPhrase, "(\\s[^\\s]+){50}")
```